# USB key to pass password in Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, security, disk-encryption

I had a room mate that put a livecd in my desktop and looked around on my machine. I caught him in the act and threw him out.

I haven't had a room mate for a while now and so as to avoid the livecd issue again I encrypted the hard drive, the machine is running centos 6.3.

Is there anyway that I can avoid typing the password in each time if I have usb key in the machine to feed the password to the system?

**Additional question.**

Is there anything you can suggest to solve the problem I have ? Thanks

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, RHEL (and by extension CentOS) does not yet support using key material on a USB drive to unlock the boot drive.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried a YubiKey](http://yubico.com/yubikey)?

[I take no credit for this, having seen it at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/321773/what-software-can-encrypt-system-disk-with-keyfile/321781#321781), but have it on good authority that it works.  I'm ordering one for my Truecrypt-encrypted system partitions at the moment.